# remote control Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have read somewhere that you are able to remotely control a raspberry Pi. I have already tried VNC, and tried finding TeamViewer for Raspbian, unfortunately without luck. Is it really possible or not to gain control via RJ45 Cable of the Pi's graphical interface, and if so, could you please place instructions on how to get it up and running.

Thank you!

PS: I have Linux Mint 16 Petra, Mac OS X 10.9, Windows 7 Enterprise on my computers, and Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi. Everything is to the most up-to-date version!

Comment: Apart from asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation is off topic on Super User, this also does not show what you have tried. Please read http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Why don't you install VNC and check it out? Or you could simply google ["raspberry pi vnc"](https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry%20pi%20vnc) to get your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest, most bone-head simple way to make a connection for what you're thinking is to `sudo apt-get install gitso` on both **Linux** machines.  Read the documentation if you must, otherwise set one to *provide support* and the other to *get help*

You can bootstrap your way in by `ssh -X <user>@ip.ad.re.ss` and then execute `gitso`.  You could make it painless by enabling password-less ssh login by reading a howto.

I know nothing of Windows.

Comment: I'll definitely give it a try. I never heard of 'gitso' but, if it works for the RPi, thanks a mil.

Comment: I know this is an old post but it's still worth saying that VNC works fine.  You need to start the service (or somehow get it to auto-start) on the RaspPi first.